# Turn pandas series to series of lists or numpy array to array of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a series `s`

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2])
```

What is an efficient way to make `s` look like

```
0    [1]
1    [2]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach that extracts into array and extends to `2D` by introducing a new axis with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) -

```
pd.Series(s.values[:,None].tolist())
```

Here's a similar one, but extends to `2D` by reshaping -

```
pd.Series(s.values.reshape(-1,1).tolist())
```

Runtime test using [`@P-robot's setup`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39797640/3293881) -

```
In [43]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,10,1000))

In [44]: %timeit pd.Series(np.vstack(s.values).tolist()) # @Nickil Maveli's soln
100 loops, best of 3: 5.77 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit pd.Series([[a] for a in s]) # @P-robot's soln
1000 loops, best of 3: 412 µs per loop

In [46]: %timeit s.apply(lambda x: [x]) # @mgc's soln
1000 loops, best of 3: 551 µs per loop

In [47]: %timeit pd.Series(s.values[:,None].tolist()) # Approach1
1000 loops, best of 3: 307 µs per loop

In [48]: %timeit pd.Series(s.values.reshape(-1,1).tolist()) # Approach2
1000 loops, best of 3: 306 µs per loop
```

Comment: Much better approach compared to mine.

Comment: @Divakar For the sake of completeness you could add an "Approach3" with `pd.Series(memoryview(s.values.reshape(-1,1)).tolist())` as it should even be faster (as least with my current config. it is) to build the `Series` on the `memoryview` (probably more visible with a larger sample).

Comment: @mgc Is it only for python3?  At my end with python 2.7, I am getting this error : `"NotImplementedError: tolist() only supports byte views"`, when trying to do : `memoryview(s.values.reshape(-1,1)).tolist()`.

Comment: @Divakar you're right it's only python 3. My bad, i don't use python 2.7 that much. I added "with my config" (but i should have define it : python 3.5.2 / numpy 1.11.1) because I can not guarantee that to be the case across all versions (so finally it might not be such a good candidate as an "Approach 3" for your answer!)

Comment: @mgc Still very much appreciate the feedback and for someone with python3 could try it out too!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result to still be a pandas `Series` you can use the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) method :

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s = pd.Series([1, 2])

In [3]: s.apply(lambda x: [x])
Out[3]: 
0    [1]
1    [2]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
import numpy as np

np.array([[a] for a in s],dtype=object)
array([[1],
       [2]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting atomh33ls' answer, here's a series of lists:

```
output = pd.Series([[a] for a in s])
type(output)
>> pandas.core.series.Series
type(output[0])
>> list
```

Timings for a selection of the suggestions:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,10,1000))

>> %timeit pd.Series(np.vstack(s.values).tolist())
100 loops, best of 3: 3.2 ms per loop

>> %timeit pd.Series([[a] for a in s])
1000 loops, best of 3: 393 µs per loop

>> %timeit s.apply(lambda x: [x])
1000 loops, best of 3: 473 µs per loop
```